# custom AdapterView With complex layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-adapterview

I am trying to make a scrollable list. the list will be populated with custom views(list items) of various sizes and at different positions (x,y). Besides the actual views there will be a few side views around surrounding the main layout where the child views will be placed. sort of like a header or footer but surrounding it all around. The total height of the list is fixed.

Right now i am just defining the complex layout in the activity xml layout and having the logic in the Activity where it is housed. I want to be able to populate it via an adapter(since my data for the views comes from a database) and encapsulate it in a custom component to be reused.

**the layout i want to encapsulate. this is the layout i am currently using**

```
RelativeLayout (fixed height h)
-->LinearLayout (side views around the main framelayout)
------ .......
------ (extra views)
------ .......
-->FrameLayout (to be populated dynamically)
------ .......
------ (dynamicly added child views)
------ .......
```

**How do i create a custom AdapterView that supports these things?**

P.S. I havent done complex custom components other than introductory tutorials on the web

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: Why are trying to make scrollable listview..Listview with default has scroll..

Comment: it's gonna be like a list view. i want to clarify that there are other items in there not passed by adapter and the list items are not fixed in size and they aren't positioned sequentially either. they are of different size and positioned at different (x,y) on the layout